# Error 1103 con AppInventor

Tags: php, mysql, appinventor

Verán, tengo que hacer una base de datos con App Inventor.
Esta tiene una tabla **usuario**, que tiene las variables *dni* y *clave*.
Es una tabla que está en MySQL.
Al entrar el usuario debe indicar su dni y su clave y si estas aparecen en la base de datos, el usuario podrá entrar en la página principal.

Código PHP:

```
<?php
    $host="127.0.0.1";
    $usuario="root";
    $clave="";
    $banco="terciario";

    $dbcon=new MySQLi("$host","$usuario","$clave","$banco");

    if($dbcon->connect_error)
        echo "Error";

    $dni=$_POST['dni'];
    $clave=$_POST['clave'];

    $sql=$dbcon->query("SELECT * from usuario where dni='$dni' and clave='$clave'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)==1)
        echo "Exito";
    else
        echo "Error";
?>
```

Y aquí está el código que utilizo en App Inventor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ejecutar el programa me sale este mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como arreglo este error?
He hecho pruebas accediendo a la BBDD directamente con PHP y funciona, por lo que el problema esta en App Inventor.

PD: La carpeta donde guardo el fichero PHP que utilizo es *C:/xampp/htdocs/php/*.

Otra cosa, este es el código tal como lo tengo actualmente, pero traducido al inglés:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualización: Vale, lo que realmente ocurre es que no puede el programa conectarse a la BBDD si está en host local, por lo que tengo que subir la BBDD y los ficheros PHP a un servidor estilo 000webhost. Tendre que ponerme manos a la obra.

Comment: En efecto, el formato no es el adecuado. Pasa que no sabría si "PonerTexto" equivale a PostText en la documentación de appInventor :/  Ahora, yo lo que haría es hacer debug al llamado del código PHP y hacer algún print_r de $_POST allá, para ver qué envía tu app inventor

Comment: @Alfabravo equivale a PutText. He probado a cambiarlo a PostText pero sale el mismo error. ¿Como hago ese debug que dices?

Comment: Aparte, he editado para mostrar en inglés mi código, ya que veo que eso hará más fácil entenderlo.

Comment: Tambien he añadido información sobre mi base de datos MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Viendo tu problema, todo indica que esa no parece ser la forma correcta de enviar los parámetros. Recuerda que un mensaje POST es una URL y un BODY (cuerpo del mensaje) con un conjunto de elementos clave-valor.

En una pregunta [similar](https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/http-post-format-problem/11506/6), alguien sugirió usar un diccionario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así le añades correctamente tus datos a la petición, en un formato que el script PHP puede entender.

PD. Para revisar en PHP qué recibes, revisa la documentación de [`print_r()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) y [`var_dump()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).

Comment: ¿Los diccionarios pueden almacenar claves foraneas? Porque en el futuro voy a necesitar eso. Aún así, revisare lo de testear PHP.